# Pinterest "Pin it" button breaking 'back' in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pinterest

I recently found out that in Internet Explorer (v9 at least), the "Pin it" button for Pinterest is breaking 'back' functionality in the browser. Right-clicking on it shows an entry like 'http://assets.pinterest.com/pidget.html' as the previous page.

Looks like Pinterest is adding an iFrame and IE is adding its address to the history.  Clicking 'back' doesn't do anything.  Is this a known issue and is there a fix for this?

Comment: I was also having this problem in IE9. Only on gallery/image heavy pages. I read somewhwere that upgrading to IE10 fixed it. I upgraded to 10 and it semi fixed it. Back button now works but needs two clicks. Also found that using google chrome there is no issue and works fine. Hope they fix this soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, as a temporary solution (other than removing the 'pin it' button), from reading their code, I believe (not tested) that you could add a part to the `<script>` call to disable logging, like this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" data-pin-do-not-log="true"></script>
```

This works but doesn't apply for me because I load the script asynchronously and I use a `load` command, so what I did was I copied the pinit.js file locally to the server, and changed the part that says

```
if(a.v.config["do-not-log"]||a.a.doNotLog===true)
```

to

```
if(a.v.config["do-not-log"]||a.a.doNotLog===true||true)
```

looks like it's doing some sort of log in an iframe.

Comment: this only worked for me when I had data-pin-do-not-log="true". Really nice find though. Also, you can do data-pin-debug="true" to verify. It logs: 'Host page or server has asked us not to log.' Thanks!

Comment: @SamSimmons cool it worked, it was just a theory. I'll update the response so people don't have to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  I added the website to my list of restricted sites by going to "Tools", then "Internet options", then "Security".  It seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've raised it with PInterest here https://help.pinterest.com/requests/884162

Thier response. Pretty much a brush off.

---

Hi ,

Information on how to add the Pin It button to your website or product pages is available here:

http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/

More advanced documentation is available here:

https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21101982

We regret that we're unable to provide coding support. Because issues with adding the Pin It button can be caused by conflicts with different parts of your setup it is usually best when someone that is familiar with your setup troubleshoots it. You may also want to try searching the web to see if others have had similar issues especially people that are using a similar site platform or language.

We request that you use our help articles to get the information you need as quickly as possible. If there’s additional information you’d like our team to know, you can reply to this message.

Thanks for writing and happy pinning!

- The Pinterest Team

Comment: I can't see others' requests - I would be very grateful if you'd update here if you get a response from Pinterest!

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary bug when we first pushed the new Pin It button and should no longer be an issue, since we removed the logging frame shortly after it was reported. Sorry for the trouble!